# How to display data from localstorage using handlebars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

In my program i fetch data from console and store it in localstorage and webSQL . Now i want to display the stored data from localstorage using handlebar. I used the following code:

```
 console.log(response); // To get data from console
 var offer = JSON.stringify(response);  
localStorage.setItem("object",offer);  // saved in localstorage
var seasons= localStorage.getItem("object");  // get data from localstorage and saved in variable seasons
var mysource = document.getElementById("detailstemplate").innerHTML;
var mytemplate = Handlebars.compile(mysource);
var myresult = mytemplate(seasons);
document.getElementById("divOffers").innerHTML = myresult;
```

I used the last 4 lines to display data using handlebars. But it is not working. Please correct the error.Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? What is your *question* (the title should really be a short summary of your problem)? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The data in Local Storage is stored and returned as JSON. Have you tested Handlebars using a local object e.g. a var as an object literal?

Answer (score 0):

```
   var season = localStorage.getItem("cart");
        var season2 = $.parseJSON(season);
        var mytemp = $("#mainmenu-template").html(); // Grab the template script
        var ourtemp = Handlebars.compile(mytemp); // Compile the template
        var resultnew = ourtemp(season2);
        $("#divMainMenu").append(resultnew);
```